# How to make ggplot plot variance using stat_summary

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, variance

I would like to  use stat_sumarasi to plot the variance but I don't know the name of the function and can't find it in the documentation.

stat_summary(geom = "errorbar", fun = "mean") Instead of mean I want variance. You can use the following dataframe:

```
 >>> Data
        Sample     temp
        [Chr]      [num]
    0   1          6.9
    1   1          6.8
    2   1          5.5
    3   1          3.6
    4   1          2.5
    5   1          2.3
    6   2          2.8
    7   2          13.4
    8   2          19
    9   2          18.7
   10   2          20
```

Comment: Try "var" instead of "mean"

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunatly, doesn't work it say: geom_errorbar requires the following missing aesthetics: ymin and ymax or y, xmin and xmax